# my code seem to have trouble when it comes to getting the data from the input textbox to python flask

Tags: python, flask

my code in python and in html have problems in the direction of the data to go to

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main_login_design.css">
    <title>Projekt Tsarli</title>
    <nav class="header">
        <div class="header">
            <p class="logo">Projekt Tsarli</p>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ai_chatbox">
        <div>
            <form action="{{url_for(main_login)}}" method="post">
                <input name="ai_chatbox" placeholder="Enter your thoughts here" class="chatbox_design">
                <button type="submit">Enter</button>
                <br>
                <br>
            </form>
        </div>        
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

and in python:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def main_login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        thoughts_ai = request.args.get("ai_chatbox")
        return render_template('main_login.html')
 


 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

im trying to connect the info of what the user input in the textbox to python and to return it in html but it doesnt seems to work, ive tried everything.

Comment: You are missing `elif request.method == "GET":` you will never see the page

Answer (score 1):

You can access the value entered in the text box using `request.form.get("ai_chatbox")`. But I think you are not passing this value to the template for rendering.

```
def main_login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        thoughts_ai = request.form.get("ai_chatbox")

        # Process the form data or perform any required actions

        return render_template('index.html', thoughts_ai=thoughts_ai)

    return render_template('index.html')
```

and add these to where you want it. `{{thoughts_ai}}` will get what you put in the `render_template('index.html', thoughts_ai=thoughts_ai)`.

```
    <div>
        <p>User Input: {{ thoughts_ai }}</p>
    </div>
```